# How to see terminal commands generated by GUI actions

Tags: command-line, gui

I am new to Linux and only know my way around because of the GUI.  Is there a way to see the equivalent commands on the terminal to do the same things as using the GUI?  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Probably not, because a GUI most of the time isn't calling the same command as a user would type in the terminal.

That said, if you want to know more about terminal commands, these are some usefull sites which explain common commands:

[General use](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)

[Some common commands](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting#Commands)

[A more advanced list](http://beginlinux.com/desktop_training/ubuntu/ubuntu-terminal-guide)

Answer (score 0):

*I know this is a few years late but was cited as an answer to a similar question (making both answers wrong). While this answer more correctly answers the other question, I couldn't find where to respond.*

You can find out by using `strace`.  Run the GUI or command line software or command from the terminal preceded by `strace` e.g.

```
strace gedit
```

or

```
strace ls
```

Quoting from `man strace`:

> In  the simplest case `strace` runs the specified command until it exits.  It intercepts and records the system calls which are called by a process and the signals which are received by a process.  The name of each system call,
>          its arguments and its return value are printed on standard error or to the file specified with the `-o` option.
>
> `strace` is a useful diagnostic, instructional, and debugging tool.  System administrators, diagnosticians and trouble-shooters will find it invaluable for solving problems with programs for which  the  source  is  not  readily
>          available  since they do not need to be recompiled in order to trace them.  Students, hackers and the overly-curious will find that a great deal can be learned about a system and its system calls by tracing even ordinary programs.  And programmers will find that since system calls and signals are events that happen at the user/kernel interface, a close examination of this boundary is very useful for bug isolation, sanity checking and  attempting
>          to capture race conditions.
>
> Each line in the trace contains the system call name, followed by its arguments in parentheses and its return value.  An example from stracing the command `cat /dev/null` is:
>
> ```
>   open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY) = 3
> ```

Comment: strace is interesting, but it doesn't show equivalent *commands*, it "records the system calls" which are not the same thing.